# Get changelog before installing updates on Solaris/OmniOS?

Tags: solaris, update, omnios

On Solaris `pkg update -nv` will give a list the new packages.

On CentOS can one read the changelog for each package by `yum changelog`.

Is it possible to read the changelog for each of the available packages before installing them on Solaris/OmniOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how OmniOS provides them, but Solaris does not put ChangeLogs in the packages.   For Solaris Support Repository Updates (SRUs), the change information is provided in a README document on the My Oracle Support portal instead.  Some bug id & CVE id information is provided as metadata in the packages, but that would give you a bare list of id numbers without any description - the SRU README gives better info than that.

Comment: On OmniOS, the packages also only include versions and license. You can get that info with `pkg info -r yourPackage` and `pkg info --license yourPackage`.